# Bootstrap tabs inside Owl carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel, bootstrap-tabs

I've seen a lot of questions about placing an Owl carousel control inside a Bootstrap tab pane. For instance, [Owl Carousel not working inside Bootstrap Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72727759/owl-carousel-not-working-inside-bootstrap-tabs) and [Owl Carousel broken inside tab panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56543812/owl-carousel-broken-inside-tab-panel).

I'd like to implement the opposite: to place Bootstrap tab panes inside a slide (`div`) within Owl carousel. Unfortunately, it doesn't work: clicking on a button group doesn't switch the tabs. If I get the slide outside of the carousel, it starts working. I've found what the problem is. Owl Carousel creates copies of the slide (`owl-item cloned`) to make the slides look looped. As the result, there are several button groups with the same `id` and `name`. They are conflicting, so switching tabs doesn't work.

Is there a way to workaround the issue somehow? Or Owl carousel supports simple, cloneable, types of slides only?

If I set `loop` to `false`, it helps, but I'd like to keep the slides looped.

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        loop: false, // <--------
        nav: true,
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>OwlCarousel Slider</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
 
      <div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
                  <div> Your Content Tab 1</div>
                  <div> Your Content Tab 1 </div>
                  <div> Your Content Tab 1</div>
                  <div> Your Content Tab 1 </div>
                  <div> Your Content Tab 1</div>
                  <div> Your Content Tab 1</div>
                  <div> Your Content Tab 1</div>
                </div>    
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
            <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
                  <div> Your Content Tab 2</div>
                  <div> Your Content Tab 2</div>
                  <div> Your Content Tab 2</div>
                  <div> Your Content Tab 2</div>
                  <div> Your Content Tab 2Tab 2Tab 2</div>
                  <div> Your Content Tab 2Tab 2</div>
                  <div> Your Content Tab 2</div>
                </div> 
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
 
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    speed: 800,
    margin:15,
    autoplay:true,
    nav:false,
    responsive:{
      0:{
        items:1
      },
      600:{
        items:3
      },
      1000:{
        items:3
      }
    }
  });
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    e.target // newly activated tab
    e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
    $(".owl-carousel").trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
    });
  });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```